# Checking screenSize is not working

Tags: android, screen-size

This is my code for checking screen sizes and changing the `FrameLayout` size.

```
    FrameLayout topLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.topLayout);

    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
    double x = Math.pow(dm.widthPixels/dm.xdpi,2);
    double y = Math.pow(dm.heightPixels / dm.ydpi, 2);
    double screenInches = Math.sqrt(x + y);

    if (screenInches < 5) topLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout
    .LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,170));
    if (screenInches >= 5 && screenInches < 7) topLayout
    .setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout 
    .LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 200));
    else topLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout
    .LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 230));
```

I don't know why its not working.

Comment: what are the errors if any  ?

Comment: No errors. Just the height of FrameLayout is reduced...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DisplayMetrics` .

> A structure describing general information about a display, such as
>   its size, density, and font scaling.

```
   DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

   int DeviceTotalWidth = metrics.widthPixels;
   int DeviceTotalHeight = metrics.heightPixels;
   FrameLayout topLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.topLayout);

   topLayout.getLayoutParams().height= (DeviceTotalHeight/4); // Use Your Logic
```

Now you can use your `screenInches` logic simply .

Comment: @Omuradil Glad to help .Move ahead .

Answer (score 0):

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
((Activity)mContext)getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
```

Comment: Darshan Kachhadiya, Not understand... could you explain a little deployed?

Comment: u can get device height then u set % of device height 
like if u use framelayout height 10 % than u can use height 10 % for frame layout

Comment: no but if uuse this code outside activity then u need mcontext or ur question is than screen size not working so i give solution for getting screen size

Comment: you did't understand. i  need to change height of FrameLayout... but does'nt work...

Answer (score 0):

in order to change layout parameter you have to do this:

```
topLayout.getLayoutParams().width = 100;
topLayout.getLayoutParams().height = 100;
```